# Replace Values in a column wiht NA if values from another column are not 1

Tags: r, replace, na

I've got a Spatialpointsdataframe. I would like to replace values in a column with NA if in the same row from another column the value is not 1.
For example: 
I've got a coulmn roadtype and a column joincount. If in a row the joincount is not 1, i want to replace the roadtype with NA.
Any idea how to do that?
Thanks for your help

Comment: So easy, I tried this: shape$name_wegty[which(is.na(shape$Count !=1))] = NA. It did not work though. Any idea why? Thanks a lot

Comment: Make a [minimal reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) and show the expected result.

Comment: What is it that you think the `is.na` in  `is.na(shape$Count !=1)` is doing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

```
library(sp)
S@coords[,'roadtype'][S@coords[,'jointcount']!=1] <- NA
S
# SpatialPoints:
#     jointcount roadtype
#[1,]          1        3
#[2,]          4       NA
#[3,]          3       NA
#[4,]          1        1
#[5,]          1        4
```

#### data

```
jointcount = c(1,4,3,1,1)
roadtype = c(3,2,5,1,4)
S <- SpatialPoints(data.frame(jointcount,roadtype))
```